# Unable to update selected column in the SQLite database - Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I need to updated selected columns in my database, however i am unable to get the updated data.As soon as the user click on next button, the data should get updated.There are total 12 fields that needs to be updated in the table.

Note: dba is DBAdapter i.e the database and myDB is SQLiteDatabase

```
 nxt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_nxt);
          nxt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {


                String b1=t1.getText().toString();
                String b2=goal_website_trying_to_achieve_edttxt.getText().toString();
                String b3=communicate_edttxt.getText().toString();
                String b4=success_look_like_edttxt.getText().toString();
                String b5=usp_insights_edttxt.getText().toString();
                String b6=act_edttxt.getText().toString();
                String b7=market_edttxt.getText().toString();
                String b8=your_current_website_www_edttxt.getText().toString();
                String b9=your_current_website_good_edttxt.getText().toString();
                String b10=your_current_website_bad_edttxt.getText().toString();
                String b11=your_current_website_type_edttxt.getText().toString();
                String b12=your_current_website_update_edttxt.getText().toString();
                String b13=your_current_website_supporting_edttxt.getText().toString();






                if(!validatescreen2()){
                    return;
                }

                else{

                    dba.open();



                    String updatequery = "UPDATE "+ DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE+ " SET ";

                    updatequery = updatequery + " KEY_MESSAGE_1 = " + b1 +"WHERE" +"_id"+mRowId +",";
                    updatequery = updatequery + " KEY_MESSAGE_2 = " + b2 +"WHERE" +"_id"+mRowId + ",";
                    updatequery = updatequery + " KEY_MESSAGE_3 = " + b3 +"WHERE" +"_id"+mRowId + ",";
                    updatequery = updatequery + " KEY_MESSAGE_4 = " + b4 +"WHERE" +"_id"+mRowId + ",";
                    updatequery = updatequery + " KEY_MESSAGE_5 = " + b5 +"WHERE" +"_id"+mRowId + ",";
                    updatequery = updatequery + " KEY_MESSAGE_6 = " + b6 + "WHERE" +"_id"+mRowId +"',";
                    updatequery = updatequery + " KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_1 = " + b7 + "WHERE" +"_id"+mRowId +",";
                    updatequery = updatequery + " KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_2 = " + b8 +"WHERE" +"_id"+mRowId + ",";
                    updatequery = updatequery + " KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_3 = " + b9 +"WHERE" +"_id"+mRowId + ",";
                    updatequery = updatequery + " KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_TYPE = " + b10 + "WHERE" +"_id"+mRowId +",";
                    updatequery = updatequery + " KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_NEED = " + b11 + "WHERE" +"_id"+mRowId +",";
                    updatequery = updatequery + " KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_OTHER = " + b12 + "WHERE" +"_id"+mRowId ;

                    try{
                        myDB.execSQL(updatequery);
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        Log("Caught while writing response" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }finally{
                        if(myDB != null)myDB.close();

                    }

                    showDialog(DIALOG_ID);

                    dba.close();
                }


            }

          });
```

changes made

```
String updatequery = "UPDATE"+ DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE+ " SET "+ DBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE_1 +"= "+ b1 +

                                DBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE_2  +"= "+ b2 +
                                DBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE_3  +"= "+ b3 +
                                DBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE_4  +"= "+ b4 +
                                DBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE_5  +"= "+ b5 +
                                DBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE_6 +"= "+ b6+
                                DBAdapter.KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_1  +"= "+ b7 +
                                DBAdapter.KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_2  +"= "+ b8 +
                                DBAdapter.KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_3  +"= "+ b9+
                                DBAdapter.KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_TYPE  +"= "+ b10 +
                                DBAdapter.KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_NEED  +"= "+ b11 +               
                                DBAdapter.KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_OTHER +"= " + b12  + "WHERE" + DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID + "=" + mRowId ;



logcat error file


01-30 12:02:24.136: W/System.err(2645): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 12:02:24.136: W/System.err(2645):     at com.example.sales.Newform_Screen2$3.onClick(Newform_Screen2.java:165)
01-30 12:02:24.136: W/System.err(2645):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
01-30 12:02:24.136: W/System.err(2645):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
01-30 12:02:24.136: W/System.err(2645):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-30 12:02:24.136: W/System.err(2645):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-30 12:02:24.136: W/System.err(2645):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-30 12:02:24.136: W/System.err(2645):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-30 12:02:24.136: W/System.err(2645):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Comment: @Subburaj : not getting updated

Comment: Whether your query is executing??

Answer (score 3):

Your SQL query is incorrect. It should be in the form --

```
UPDATE <table>
   SET <field1> = <value1>,
       <field2> = <value2> ...
 WHERE <indexfield> = <id>
```

Also, you'll need to escape the values, so it's 
    SET FieldName = 'value'

You'd be better off taking advantage of the [`update`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) method.

As follows:

```
String updatequery = "UPDATE"+ DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE+ " SET "+ DBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE_1 +"= '"+ b1 + "'," +

                                DBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE_2  +"= '"+ b2 + "'," +
                                DBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE_3  +"= '"+ b3 + "'," +
                                DBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE_4  +"= '"+ b4 + "'," +
                                DBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE_5  +"= '"+ b5 + "'," +
                                DBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE_6 +"= '"+ b6 + "'," +
                                DBAdapter.KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_1  +"= '"+ b7 + "'," +
                                DBAdapter.KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_2  +"= '"+ b8 + "'," +
                                DBAdapter.KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_3  +"= '"+ b9 + "'," +
                                DBAdapter.KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_TYPE  +"= '"+ b10 + "'," +
                                DBAdapter.KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_NEED  +"= '"+ b11 + "'," +        
                                DBAdapter.KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_OTHER +"= '" + b12  + "' " + "WHERE" + DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID + "=" + mRowId ;
```

It's still a horrible way to access the database. What you really should do is this --

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put( DBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE_1, b1 );
values.put( DBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE_2, b2 );
....
String filter = String.format( "%s = '%s'", DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId );
myDB.update( DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE, values, filter, null );
```

Comment: You're still lacking the single-quotes around the values, and the commas between the assignments. As is, you don't even have a space between the value and the next field name. Updating answer.

Comment: as per changes suggested by you..iam getting this error..please refer the above logcat

Comment: Change the `String.format` format to `"%s = '%s'"` -- I presumed that mRowId would be a numeric type rather than a String. May I recommend you spend a bit of time getting familiar with the excellent documentation for the Android SDK? All of the concepts above are explained well.

Comment: as per your suggestion i made the changes but still getting nullpointer exception